Flutter Sign In LOGOUT exception null with twitter (twitter_api_v2) Desktop windows bug
I'm having trouble integrating the Twitter API v2 for my Flutter desktop application on Windows. When I launch the Twitter sign-in flow, the console displays a 'logout exception null' error, and I don't receive the user's username and email data
I try this code below :
enter image description here
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

see picture                ...
